# what is url shorthand in a filesystem

Tags: url, io, filesystems, uri

This should be pretty simple  I need know what dots mean in a url such as 
`"../../../Program Files (x86)/Filed/examples/tmw_desert_spacing.png"`

I'm assuming this is some kind of shorthand that means "the same as the current directory"/etc/folder/file.png a link to an article that explains this would be nice too, my google search turned up nothing since im not even sure this is called a url. thanks

more info: the program im writing won't except this as the file name, I need to konw what need to change to become acceptable.

Comment: It means "up one directory from where you are now"

Comment: This is so not a C++ question.

Comment: You need to show us the code where you are trying to use that as a file name and show us the error message or describe what you mean by "wont accept".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to RFC 3986:

> The path segments "." and "..", also known as dot-segments, are
>   defined for relative reference within the path name hierarchy.  They
>   are intended for use at the beginning of a relative-path reference
>   (Section 4.2) to indicate relative position within the hierarchical
>   tree of names.

The takeaway is that they have the same meaning as in paths on a linux or windows system - single dot means "the directory specified by the preceding part of the path", two dots mean "the parent directory of the directory specified by the preceding part of

Comment: That's a well-researched answer.

Comment: Got to provide those references.

Comment: Thanks that helps alot. Thanks to your answer i was able to find this http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt the full documentation on URL. my specific question is answered on page 35 if anyone wants to know